# Errors in Android Manifest and xml files

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated Android Studio and many errors have suddenly appeared:

In Android Manifest:
[image: Manifest attribute not allowed error]

[image: Manifest unresolved class error]

In activity xml files:
[image: xml URI not registered error]

I have already tried restarting Android Studio, Invalidate Cache, and Clean/Rebuild Project.
Is there any way to find what is causing the errors?

Edit: here is my build.gradle file. How do I edit the buildToolsVersion?

[image: build.gradle]

Comment: you have to change your gradle/dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Update your  `buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"` make sure version higher then 25.0.0 in app > build.gradle

After buildToolsVersion change you need to clean project and rebuild project.